# Like button not showing up in firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox

I have a problem where the like button doesn't work on my page in firefox, but works in all other browsers.

Please look at my link: http://idhair.eu/swag/hinnerup.html

Don't mind the layout, it can look messy.

Comment: Okay, but on some computers they do not show.

Answer (score 0):

Your Like buttons may not be showing because the page you are linking to may not be available to the logged-in user. If you logout of Facebook, the Like buttons *should* display correctly. Any viewer restrictions you have on the content / pages will prevent certain users from seeing the like button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to logout of facebook, but that didn't change anything. I do have a fan gate on the index page. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have embedded 
`<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` script twice, first time after first `<div id="fb-root"></div>`, then using

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=********";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

my chrome inspection also says fbinit has initialized before, also you have two `<div id="fb-root"></div>` 
you can do it like this,removing the first JS. and having one fb-root div.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '*******',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true
        });

    };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```